# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 8

Tags: python, pandas, parsing

I am trying to read a CSV using `pd.read_csv`, but I get an error:

> UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call
>   last) pandas_libs\parsers.pyx in
>   pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_tokens()
>
> pandas_libs\parsers.pyx in
>   pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_with_dtype()
>
> pandas_libs\parsers.pyx in
>   pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._string_convert()
>
> pandas_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers._string_box_utf8()
>
> **UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in
>   position 8: invalid start byte**
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> UnicodeDecodeError
>  Traceback (most recent call last)
>   ipython-input-84-c0272ccf19e6 in module

Sample of my data:

```
Time,Type,Instrument,Product,Qty.,Avg. price,Status
3/27/2019 13:46,BUY,MFSL,MIS,1600,115.25,COMPLETE
3/27/2019 13:46,BUY,MFSL,MIS,500,115.3,COMPLETE
```

i have already tried checking if there is an invalid character (using Notepad++). "Show all characters"

I couldn't find any difference when comparing this file with a similar one that could be loaded.
Just Need help Troubleshooting the above, If someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: The file is not UTF-8 encoded, and 0xa0 is a non-breaking space in other encodings like `latin1` and `cp1252` among others.  Use the right encoding.

Comment: i tried latin1 it works , Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data you posted works fine for me, but it's several degrees removed from your source. Specifying an encoding when opening the file may fix the problem. You can do this a couple of ways: use the codecs package to open the file and let that decide the encoding, or specify the encoding in csv_read()

```
    import codecs

doc = codecs.open('document','rU','UTF-16') #open for reading with "universal" type set

df = pandas.read_csv(doc, sep=',')
```

You also might want to sanitize your column names, as spaces and decimals can cause problems in referencing.

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.strip().str.lower().str.replace(' ', '_').str.replace('(', '').str.replace(')', '').str.replace('.', '')
```

Comment: Will try both in 2 hrs from now.. and let you know Brad. Thank You.

Comment: With this Encoding (16).. this gives me an error: UnicodeError: UTF-16 stream does not start with BOM

Comment: Also, I am using Excel to save this file.. I have tried to save in MS DOS Csv as well.